# How to populate a ListView based on the action in previous activity?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

Currently there are three buttons in my main activity. Each button opens a new activity with a `ListView` containing different photos. Each `ListView` has a different size.

I've created a schema of my question:[image: schema]

My question is: How to create only one activity that contains a `ListView` and populate it with different photos depending on which button is clicked?

I suppose I have to use `intent.putExtra` to define button number and use this number in `if` statement to add images to `ListView`. But I'm not sure in this solution.

Comment: And you should show your efforts or community will keep down voting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why aren't you sure about this solution?  
If the layout of the activity to be opened is the same in all 3 cases and the only difference is the contents of the list, then it is the simplest and best solution.  
Just pass an integer value to the intent and check it in the onCreate() of the activity that is opened.  Depending on the value create and set the adapter for the list and you' re done.  
This is the most efficient way and less resources consuming.

Answer (score 3):

Create 3 `Fragments` and on each button press just load required `Fragment`. Each of those `Fragments` should have `ListView/RecyclerView` in them and use different data sources. That is it :) This, of course, can be implemented in several ways, but that is how I would approach this.

---

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this

Answer (score 1):

Create 1 custom adapter which takes Arraylist of intergers(i.e Resource id's) and set those id to imageview in adapter.

in activity onclick of button add the related id's to Arraylist and pass via intent to next activit. You can pass and get arraylist from intent like below

1) intent.putStringArrayListExtra("array_list", array_list);
2) intent.getStringArrayListExtra("array_list");